# Had a session run or ran?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following (part) sentences is correct?

- ...had a session ran by a leader.
- ...had a session run by a leader.

The second sounds better to me but I can't find any reference to why.

Comment: This is whiz-deletion from ' ... had a session which was run by a leader.' or  ' ... had a session which had been run by a leader.'  Whiz-deletion has been covered many times before on ELU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *run* because it's being used as an adjective, and when a verb is used as an adjective you need the past participle.

*Ran* in "The session ran" is a simple past-tense verb describing what the session itself did.

You want what is almost a passive-voice, "the session was run": "...had a session which was run..."

With many verbs, the simple past is the same as the past participle (like *paint/painted/painted*). Irregular verbs (*run/ran/run, drink/drank/drunk*) differ, **but** the simple past and the participle are generally so similar that thinking too much about it can cause confusion. If you make the adjectival use explicit with something like "which was run" then it should be clear.